# Dataframe r - match and sum help needed

Tags: r

I match 2 data frames in R and having an issue when duplicate records exists in the second data frame. Also, i try to index match but gives incorrect results. So my data frames are:

```
V1 <- c("AB1", "AB2", "AB3" ,"AB4" ,"AB5" ,"AB6" ,"AB7","AB8","AB9" ,"AB10")
V3 <- c ("","AB3", "","","","","AB6","","","AB11")
V4 <- c("","","","","","","","","","AB12")


df1 <- data.frame(V1,V3,V4)
df1$V2 <- 0
```

and

```
V5 <- c("AB1","AB2","AB2","AB2", "AB3", "AB4", "AB5", "AB6")
V6 <- c(1,2,2,2,3,4,5,6)
df2 <- data.frame(V5,V6)
```

I have two codes, first one incorrectly matches data and the second one works but it produces NAs. Additionally I try to return a sum when two records exists in df2 (ie AB2 should be 6 and not 2)? Any help will be appreciated.

Codes I use:

```
df1$V2[match(df2$V5,df1$V1, nomatch=0)] <- df2$V6[match(df1$V1,df2$V5, nomatch = 0)]

df1$V2 <- df2$V6[match(df1$V1,df2$V5)]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can do a join with `data.table`

```
library(data.table)
dfN <- setDT(df2)[, .(V2 = sum(V6)), .(V5)]
setDT(df1)[dfN, V2 := i.V2, on = .(V1 = V5)]
```

---

Or combine the above two as

```
setDT(df1)[setDT(df2)[df1, .(V2 = sum(V6)), 
    on = .(V5= V1), by = .EACHI, nomatch = 0], V2 := i.V2, on = .(V1 = V5)]
```

Answer (score 1):

IIUC, this is a `base` solution:

```
# Sum of V6 by V5
df2_sum <- aggregate(V6 ~ V5, df2, sum)

# Merge df1 and df2_sum by V1 and V5
merge(df1, df2_sum, by.x = "V1", by.y = "V5")
```